# date formatting in shell script via automator

Tags: shell, date, automator, launchd

i need to run a shell script included in an automator app as "run shell script" action  wherein i generate a file with this filename:

```
filename=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%k-%M)'_test.png'
```

When i run this line in terminal it works. When i run the automator app manually by clicking "play" it works. But when i add the automator app to launchctl to schedule it, this does not work anymore, what i get is:

09-22-2012-

instead of something like

09-22-2012-20-10_test.png

So where is the difference between running the automator app manually and from launchctl as a launch deamon and how do i have to change the line to make it work in both scenarios? Very weird that the formatting via launchctl works for the date but has a problem with the time values.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to have only date/time specifiers in the format string.

I don't have access to automator to test your case, but try

```
filename=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%k-%M_test.png)
```

I'm betting that something about the single-quotes you're using is causing a problem.

IHTH.